# PHP pages getting 404 in public_html

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-404, public-html

I have a couple of PHP-based projects (that are working fine locally), but I'm looking to host on the same server as my Wordpress site/portfolio.

I have put those folders in `public_html` folder in my file structure but they are generating a 404 error when I try to load them.

HTML based pages work fine, for PHP it's not. Does anyone have any ideas?
I'm sure I'm missing something fairly obvious but am at a loss at the moment...

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the permission of files. Either change it via command line,

```
find foldername -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find foldername -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Or change it via cPanel,

Change permission for files to 644 and folders to 755

Answer (score 0):

If You are using Cpanel, Please Check the folder permission you added.
Permission should be `0755` to be readable/accessible to the public.

For my case permission was `"0750"` and it was not visible to public.
Modified the folder permission to `"0755"` and It starts working.!!